# Hangouts Floating in the middle of the screen

Tags: 14.04, gnome, google-hangouts

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS GNOME Shell 3.10.4

Hangouts will on occasion decide that the bottom of my desktop is in the middle of the page and the chat windows will stay in the middle when minimized and then when I am working they will pop up each time I scroll over them as they would if they were at the bottom of the screen.

[image: Hangouts Issue Screenshot]

Another similar issue that may be related that I can think of where a program cannot recognize the correct section of my desktop is in Pinta. When using the selection tool to try and crop an image the tool grabs seemingly whatever it wants outside or inside the selection and seemingly has no idea what I selected.

Never any issues with trying to click links or any other items to note.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you enlarge your screen shot a bit as it is hard to see (at least for my computer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

To resize the browsers tab-font, I used the following chromium flag:
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--force-device-scale-factor=0.7"
in: /etc/chromium-browser/default

Unfortunately this flag affects hangouts too.